# how to get in listview dialogue box

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, dialog

Im getting a error on my listview i try many ways. I didnt got it. what im missing? What changes i should do?    if i try with arrayadapter without dialogue is runs successfully.
Im new to android.I thanks a lot in advance..

**code-**

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            viewList = Topic.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            dialogMarketList = new Dialog(Topic.this);
        dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);      
            dialogMarketList.show();
            Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int width = newDisplay.getWidth();
        lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Topic.this,R.layout.topic_row,R.id.childname, groupnamelist));
       lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
    //   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
     //   ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Topic.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,groupnamelist);
     //   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvForDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
            @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
```

> Layout of topic_row

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat-**

```
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires
   the resource ID to be a TextView
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at
   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
   01-16 17:11:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   E/AndroidRuntime(1540):  at 
   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
    android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at
   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):    at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
     450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):   at 
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): Caused by: 
     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
     450: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):   at 
     android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:343)
```

Comment: `R.id.childname` its textview or some other view? also post your `R.layout.topic_row` file

Comment: in row file why using listview? i think it should be your textview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are upto, but it seem you are trying to display listview within dialog, like below screen shot:

[image]

I achieved this with the help of your posted code with little changes, I'm posting my code just go through and let me know:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Dialog dialogMarketList;
    ListView lvForDialog;
    public String[] groupnamelist = { "one", "two", "three", "one", "two",
            "three", "one", "two", "three" };
    View viewList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewList = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main,
                null);
        dialogMarketList = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);
        dialogMarketList.show();
        Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = newDisplay.getWidth();
        lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, R.layout.topic_row, R.id.childname,
                groupnamelist));
        lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**topic_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

Comment: Yes your rite..same screen shot only i want to display. But i want to display this list view in onPostExecute. I try this same. Im getting error. My onCreate Layout name is activity_topic same layout i was replace for want u given main.xml...  My error is java.lang.NullPointerException
Topic$LoadAlltopics.onPostExecute
Topic$LoadAlltopics.onPostExecute
android.os.AsyncTask.finish

Comment: @OneManArmy this is something different error, take long breath and check your code properly.

Comment: im getting the dialogue box but the text is not displaying..help me thank a lot. what im missing to display the text..

Comment: seem, there is no data in your arraylist, check the arraylist whether its contain data or not?

Comment: there is data..light it showing and getting hide..and also check with print sts..data is there...

Comment: @OneManArmy sorry not able to trace, what sort of things you missing, further battle you have to fought, good luck.

Comment: If i taken this line android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"     Little bit the text can been seen..lightly...what can i do? TextAppearance bright is there..

Comment: ha haa.. i got the text success.. just i add this one line  android:textColor="@android:color/white"